# Python Pygame doesn't display images correctly

Tags: python, image, pygame, bmp

I'm new to Python and I started learning with "Python crash course" by Eric Matthes. I'm in the beginning of Pygame chapter and I follow the code, but my loaded images always look damaged and I don't know why. Code is from the book. First file:

```
    import pygame
    class Ship():
        def __init__(self, screen):
            """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""

    # Load the ship image and get its rect.
            self.image = pygame.image.load('ship.bmp')
            self.screen = screen
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
            self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
            self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        def blitme(self):
            self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Second file:

```
    import sys
    import pygame
    from settings import Settings
    from ship import Ship
    def run_game():
        # Initialize game and create a screen object.
        pygame.init()
        ai_settings = Settings()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
        ship = Ship(screen)
        bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

        # Start the main loop for the game.
        while True:
            # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()      
            # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.

            screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
            ship.blitme()


            pygame.display.flip()


    run_game()
```

Settings file:

```
class Settings():
       """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""
       def __init__(self):
           """Initialize the game's settings."""
           # Screen settings
           self.screen_width = 800
           self.screen_height = 600
           self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

My bmp look like that:

[image]

I tried to add different image, but no luck:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Don't you have to apply `convert()` on your image?

Comment: I don't know, there is no such thing in book code. How can I modify my code with that?

Comment: `self.image = pygame.image.load('ship.bmp').convert()` - just try it with `convert()` at the end

Comment: Nothing changes, still the same deformed image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are on a Mac, with a relatively new version of SDL. The issue is not with your code, but newer versions of SDL having a bug with Mac OS.

To resolve, you either need to downgrade your SDL to a version prior to around version 1.2 (it's around there, forgot the exact version), or work on a different operating system.

It's very annoying.. I ended up installing virtualbox and running Linux on my Mac just to be able to code pygame!

Comment: Thank you, I think that's it and I could scratch my head for ages trying to fix that code. Mac with El Captain here.

Comment: Also El Capitain! Let me know if switching to something else works for you. Here's my source btw. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to downgrade SDL so I can't 100% say its the issue, although it's very likely. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582204/images-distorted-using-pygame