# PyGame Install Issues

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to install pygame but I'm completely confused. I'm running OSX El Capitan 10.11.3. I don't know much about how python is installed or runs when programming, I've just used whatever my IDE (PyCharm currently but I don't mind changing if it helps) chose for me and so far it's worked.

I've looked at all the related questions StackOverflow offered to me while writing this and none of them have managed to get pygame working properly. Can somebody help walk me through it or point me somewhere that has a better tutorial?

Comment: You have to post your errors. Also what IDE are you using? We cannot help you without more detail.

Comment: Which pygame version have you got? Is it compatible with your python version?

Comment: @Signal the "errors" are that pygame is never found after installing it.

Comment: Are you using pip? downloading it from pygame's website? Using Pycharm's install feature?

Comment: @Signal I've tried all of those, homebrew, and anything from any other tutorial I've found. Nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: What command are you running for PIP? What error are you getting from PIP/Pycharm? What version of python? What version of PIP? What version of PyGame? We need details...

Comment: Please, post some error messages and tell us exactly the process you have followed to install it.

Answer (score 0):

To run pygame, you need 2 things:

1. SDL
2. Pygame

I don't remember the exact lines I put in terminal to get it working but these are the steps.

Since pygame depends on SDL, we need to get it. To install SDL, first install a package manager. I'll link brew: http://brew.sh

Once you have brew, type

```
brew install SDL
```

Or something of that sort. Once SDL is downloaded, you need pygame. I believe there are 2 ways to do this. 
1. Use brew to install mercurial (I think), with

```
brew install mercurial
```

Then, in command prompt, type

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame.bitbucket.org
```

To clone pygame to your computer. Pretty sure that is the right repository, not certain.

2.I believe another way to get pygame is via pip.

```
pip install pygame
```

Edit: **A quick warning!!** Read this post! If not, you may end up wasting your time installing pygame. [Python Pygame doesn't display images correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138169/python-pygame-doesnt-display-images-correctly/36140148#36140148) You are very very likely to run into an issue with images and you may want to get a virtual machine like I did to code pygame (I use ubunto and it does not have the bug mac os does with sdl).